# Why use std::type_index instead of std::type_info*

Tags: c++, c++11, rtti

I need to key some data in a map by a type. Currently I have something like this:

```
struct TypeInfoComparer
{
  bool operator()(std::type_info const* a, std::type_info const* b) const
  {
    return a->before(*b);
  };
};

std::map<std::type_info const*, Foo, TypeInfoComparer> d_fooByTypeId;
```

Which I can then look up from using (for example, in a template method having `<typename T>`:

```
auto pair = d_fooByTypeId.find(&typeid(T));
```

However today I was reading about [`std::type_index`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_index) which seems to be intended for use in such a case as this.

I'm interested in improving my C++ knowledge. Can someone please explain whether I should modify my code to use `std::type_index`, and why? Is there a reason beyond being able to remove the `TypeInfoComparer`?

Comment: Why do you think the `type_info` returned by `typeid` is persistant and unique for a given type?

Comment: @Yakk: "The result of a typeid expression is an lvalue of static type const std::type_info... The lifetime of the object referred to by the lvalue extends to the end of the program." ([expr.typeid]). He doesn't assume that it's unique; he's using the standard `before` member function in his comparator. I don't know why everyone misses that fact.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

`type_index` is "a simple wrapper for type_info which can be used as an index type in associative containers (23.4) and in unordered associative containers (23.5)". If you use `type_index` instead of `type_info*`, you will free yourself from having to provide an explicit comparator in your maps. The only cost is that you need to `#include <typeindex>`.

Another benefit is that it will allow you to switch to (or also use) hashmaps (aka unordered_maps).

On the whole, since it simplifies your code, I'd say "go for it".

Comment: and there is little reason to use a `map` as the `before` order is arbitrary.

Comment: What would be the difference between using std::type_index vs using std::type_info::hash_code()? Or I mean a size_t.

Comment: @zebrafish: `std::type_index` is a total ordering over types in which two different types are guaranteed to produce different values with a consistent order; it can be used for either ordered or unordered containers. `std::type_info::hash_code()` may return the same value for two different types, so it can only be used as a hash function. In practice, there probably isn't a difference. But that would be an implementation detail.

Answer (score 6):

I don't think using a pointer to the result returned from `typeid(x)` is guaranteed to always yield the same result. In particular it seems problematic to guarantee the same object to be returned when shared libraries are used. The intended use of `std::type_info` for sorting is to use `before()` member. The class `std::type_index` wraps this into a simoler interface.

Comment: *"I don't think using a pointer to the result returned from typeid(x) is guaranteed to always yield the same result"*... Well, it is guaranteed, by the spec, to return the *same* object everytime you use `typeid(x)`.

Comment: @Nawaz "There is no guarantee that the same std::type_info instance will be referred to by all evaluations of the typeid expression on the same type [...]" https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid under "notes"

Comment: @phön: You're right and my previous comment turned out to be wrong. However, I'm keeping my previous (incorrect) comment intact so that others dont make the same mistake.